# How to feed only half of the RNN output to next RNN output layer in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I want to feed only RNN output at odd positions to the next RNN layer. How to achieve that in tensorflow?

I basically want to build the top layer in the following diagram, which halves the sequence size. The bottom layer is just a simple RNN.

[image]

Comment: Please provide code of what you have so far and a clear diagram of what you expect.

Comment: @thushv89 Added diagram. I don't know how to write the code for the top layer yet. The bottom layer is just a simple RNN layer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

inp = layers.Input(shape=(10, 5))
out = layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)(inp)
out = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.stack(tf.unstack(out, axis=1)[::2], axis=1))(out)
out = layers.LSTM(50)(out)
out = layers.Dense(20)(out)
m = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
m.summary()
```

You get the following model. You can see the second LSTM only gets 5 timesteps from the total 10 steps (i.e. every other output of the previous layer)

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10, 5)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 50)            11200     
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 5, 50)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 50)                20200     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 20)                1020      
=================================================================
Total params: 32,420
Trainable params: 32,420
Non-trainable params: 0
```